# How to covert "My belief was shattered by the same rock called reality" to active voice?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

The Hemingway editor asks me convert all passive voices to active voices. Is it recommended to do that
1. in all cases
2. in this case

Why is it stressed that we use active voice?

Comment: Can you explain who or what the _Hemingway editor_ is? Any person (or grammar checker) that tells you to convert all active verbs to the passive (except as a grammatical exercise) demonstrates a lack of understanding of the English language. Here is another question on the same topic: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/is-using-passive-voice-bad-form

Comment: I can't determine what your actual question is. You seems to be asking multiple things, but it's not clear exactly what your main focus is. (If it's something specific to *the Hemingway editor*, this may not be the correct site.)

Comment: My apologies if i wasn't clear. My question has two parts.                                               1. How to convert "My belief was shattered by the same rock called reality" to active voice?                                                                                                                   2. In writing, is active voice preferred over passive voice for some reason? If so, why?

Comment: "Prefer the active voice over the passive voice" is common writing advice for native English speakers, based on an idea that some speakers have a tendency to "overuse" the passive voice. The advice is of dubious value even for that audience: if you're not a native speaker, it's even less likely to be helpful.